# WCF service run very slow with reliable session

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp

The server is hosted on a WPF application and use net.tcp binding for duplex channel. We have the client (.NET 4.0) to send a burst of async request to the server. After reliable session is on, the service become really slow (approx. 50-100 call/s) and callback messages aren't sent to the client.

The issue happens in two cases.

1. We send approx. 1000 messages per seconds to the server. If we send 300-500 messages is all OK.
2. We send a single message to the server with size 10-20 MB. And in this case messages from the server callbacks wait until the big message is sending.

Below are the codes for the server and client.

**Server's binding:**

(Also we tried to use standart net.tcp binding istead of custom one but it didn't help)

```
var customBinding= new CustomBinding()
                    {
                        CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 10),
                        OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 10),
                        ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 30),
                        SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0)
                    };
                       customBinding.Elements.Add(new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement()
                         {
                             MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Default,
                             ReaderQuotas =
                             {
                                 MaxBytesPerRead = int.MaxValue,
                                 MaxDepth = int.MaxValue,
                                 MaxNameTableCharCount = int.MaxValue,
                                 MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue,
                                 MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue
                             }
                         });
                       customBinding.Elements.Add(new ReliableSessionBindingElement()
                            {
                                AcknowledgementInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1),
                                FlowControlEnabled = true,
                                InactivityTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0),
                                MaxPendingChannels = 1000,
                                MaxRetryCount = 10,
                                MaxTransferWindowSize = 4096,
                                Ordered = true,
                                ReliableMessagingVersion = ReliableMessagingVersion.Default
                            });
        var tcpTransport = new TcpTransportBindingElement()
                       {
                           ChannelInitializationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                           ConnectionBufferSize =8192,
                           ListenBacklog = 10000000,
                           MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue,
                           MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
                           MaxOutputDelay= TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000),
                           MaxPendingAccepts = int.MaxValue,
                           MaxPendingConnections = 40000,
                           MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
                           PortSharingEnabled = true,
                           TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
                       };
                       tcpTransport.ConnectionPoolSettings.GroupName = "OnlineList";
                       tcpTransport.ConnectionPoolSettings.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                       tcpTransport.ConnectionPoolSettings.LeaseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                       tcpTransport.ConnectionPoolSettings.MaxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint = 40000;
                       customBinding.Elements.Add(tcpTransport);
```

**Client side configuration:**

```
BaseTimeout = 7000;
        int.MaxValue = 2147483647;
        ///Common
                CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, BaseTimeout),
                OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, BaseTimeout),
                ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, BaseTimeout*4),
               SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, BaseTimeout),
                ///Security
                Security = { Mode = SecurityMode.None },
                ///Session
                ReliableSession =
                {
                    Enabled = true,
                    InactivityTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 10, 0),
                    Ordered = true
                },
                ///Buffer and message
                MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue,
                MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
                ///ReaderQuotas
                ReaderQuotas =
                {
                    MaxBytesPerRead = int.MaxValue,
                    MaxDepth = int.MaxValue,
                    MaxNameTableCharCount = int.MaxValue,
                    MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue,
                    MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue
                },
                //Other
                PortSharingEnabled = true,
                MaxConnections = 1000,
                TransactionFlow = true,
                TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
```